# Postgres - Group types into 'other' category

Tags: postgresql

How could I group by a column, but group specific values into that column into an 'other' category.

Lets say I have a table of sales:

```
Sales:
id | price | type
1 | 1 | basic
2 | 1 | basic
3 | 2 | premium 
4 | 5 | small
5 | 3 | medium
6 | 2 | large
```

I'd like to group the following table by the type, but also group small, medium and large sales together into 1 bucket called 'other'.

The final result would look like so:

```
sum | type
2 | basic
2 | premium
10 | other
```

This works to get each type individually, but not with the subsequent grouping

```
select sum(price), type
from sales
group by type
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider selecting it so that your question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to replace `type` by 'other' when it is 'small', 'medium' or 'large', then group by using this `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN type IN ('small', 'medium', 'large') THEN 'other' ELSE type END AS type,
       SUM(price)
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1;
```

Another option is to use a `CASE` statement into a subquery to replace `type` by 'other' when it is 'small', 'medium' or 'large'; then group by in the outer subquery:

```
SELECT type, 
       sum(price)
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN type IN ('small', 'medium', 'large') THEN 'other' ELSE type END AS type,
             price
      FROM sales) AS sq
GROUP BY type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select sum(price), type
  from sales
 where not type in ('small', 'medium', 'large')
 group by type
union all
select sum(price), 'other' as type
  from sales
 where type in ('small', 'medium', 'large')
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a union all? The query I'm writing is against a very large data and that would essentially double the time taken to run, right?